# Java Code Cleaner

Tags: java, coding-style, code-cleanup

Anyone recommend a good code cleaner for Java. If it had a Netbeans plugin, that would be awesome. Just looking for something simple.

Put variables and functions in order based off scope.

Format the code (Hungarian style)

A really awesome feature would be if it could group together functions that implement a interface for a class.

Comment: Don't format your code with Hungarian notation. Please, please, please.

Comment: I agree with glowcoder. Using Hungarian goes against most Java programmers' [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Comment: Hungarian style is a [code smell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114342/what-are-code-smells-what-is-the-best-way-to-correct-them/4058079#4058079), no longer needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Alt+Shift+F in Netbeans, it should clean it up for you automatically. You can set preferences within Netbeans as well.

Comment: I have used this before. My only issue with it is that it puts the bracket on the same line that a if,while,for,ect... statement is declared on. Any idea how to change this?

Comment: @user489041 - Check out this site: http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/12/06/customize-code-formatting-in-netbeans/ - The graphic is having problems, but the instructions should still apply.

Comment: @user489041 Tools->Options->Editor->Language(Java)->Category(Braces)